# reporting many (>10) multiple regression models

Tags: regression, biostatistics, reporting

I am currently investigating the impact of age, sex, breastfeeding duration, and estradiol levels on antibody levels.
I have measured several antibody subtypes igG1,2,3,4, IgA and IgM- in both MFI (mean fluorescence in situ) and μg/ml. When an antibody binds to the protein of interest (i.e. bacteria), it emits  fluorescence which is captured and recorded as MFI. It is not so much a measure of how much antibody is present but rather the quality of the binding relationship between the antibody and the protein of interest.

I have run a multiple linear regression for each antibody in both measurements (thus, 12 overall).

How do you go about reporting a large number of multiple linear regressions?

My results and what I would like to report:

```
regress igg1ugml_log10 age_years i.term_spec 
i.breastfeed_howlong i.cesareansection, robust

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         76
                                            F(7, 68)          =       2.71
                                            Prob > F          =     0.0154
                                            R-squared         =     0.2556
                                            Root MSE          =     .23066

               |               Robust
igg1ugml_log10 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]

    age_years |   .0563172   .0187481     3.00   0.004      .018906    .0937285

    term_spec |
     Pre-term  |  -.0614238   .0763632    -0.80   0.424    -.2138043    .0909567
               |
   breastfeed_howlong |
   1-3 months  |  -.1320811   .1043057    -1.27   0.210    -.3402199    .0760577
   4-6 months  |  -.0651863   .0979009    -0.67   0.508    -.2605445    .1301719
  7-12 months  |   .0109865   .0994054     0.11   0.912    -.1873739     .209347
   >12 months  |   .0221743   .0893491     0.25   0.805    -.1561191    .2004677
               |

  cesareansection |
          Yes  |  -.0481392    .061562    -0.78   0.437    -.1709843    .0747059
         _cons |   3.446906   .0729796    47.23   0.000     3.301278    3.592535
```

---

However, I understand that it's common practice to report r squared, the number of obs, confidence interval, and coefficient for ***each*** model ... any suggestions?

Comment: Make a table with standardized results.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).

Comment: And please explain your terminology ( such as MFI)

Comment: i have edited accordingly, please view above

Comment: Journal articles and dissertations or theses in your field provide your models. Practices vary from showing almost everything as above, possibly in an appendix -- but preferably with self-explanatory variable names or with an explanation of your variable names somewhere else -- to giving only bare summaries. There isn't a single standard answer here.

Comment: I would be inclined to look for graphical solutions, rather than text presentations, because graphs can present a large amount of information in a revealing way.